# Data Filter is not working in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to get data from `json` file but "`data:{filtertype: filtertype}`" is not working. When i click on any category that show this **error**:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

.
My code is below please help.
Thanks in advance.

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $( ".current" ).click(function() {
        $(".portfolio-style").hide();
        $(".homeportfolioloader").show();
        var filtertype = $(this).data("filter");
        $.ajax({
           url:'portfolio-images.html',
           type:'POST',
           dataType:"json",
           data:{filtertype: filtertype},
       }).done(function(data) {
            if(data) {
                var li  = "";
                $.each(data.filtertype, function( index, value ) {
                    console.log("Index: " + index.pimg_id);
                    console.log("Value: " + value.pimg_id);
                    li +="<li class='"+value.pcat_slug+"'><img src='images/portfolio/logo/"+value.pcat_slug+"/"+value.pimg_name+"'/></li>";
                });
                $(".portfolio-style").empty();
                $(".portfolio-style").append(li);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".homeportfolioloader").hide();
                    $('.portfolio-style').fadeIn(800);
                }, 4000); 
            }
       });
   });  
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>Get Data Using Json</h1>
<div class="portfolio-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="current" data-filter="all" style="cursor: pointer !important;">All</a></li>
        <li><a class="current" data-filter="mobileapps" style="cursor: pointer !important;">Mobile Apps</a></li>
        <li><a class="current" data-filter="illustrations" style="cursor: pointer !important;">Illustrations</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="homeportfolioloader" style="display: none;"></div>
<ul class="portfolio-style"></ul>
```

Comment: JSON.stringify({filtertype: filtertype})

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you for your reply.
You mean I should replace this line "data:{filtertype: filtertype}" with above?

Comment: are you trying to send json data to your backend code ?

Comment: Yes. You may check it live: http://globaloid.com/json-work/

Comment: how can you handle it on `html`?

Comment: I am handling it in html like this: 
{
 "mobileapps": [
  {
  "pimg_id":"1",
  "pimg_name":"logo-1.jpg",
  "pimg_catid":"1",
  "pcat_slug":"mobile-apps",
  "pcat_name":"Mobile Apps"
},
{
  "pimg_id":"2",
  "pimg_name":"logo-2.jpg",
  "pimg_catid":"1",
  "pcat_slug":"mobile-apps",
  "pcat_name":"Mobile Apps"
}
 ],
"illustrations": [
{  
  "pimg_id":"2",
  "pimg_name":"logo-3.jpg",
  "pimg_catid":"2",
  "pcat_slug":"illustrations",
  "pcat_name":"Illustrations"
},
{  
  "pimg_id":"2",
  "pimg_name":"logo-4.jpg",
  "pimg_catid":"2",
  "pcat_slug":"illustrations",
  "pcat_name":"Illustrations"
}]}

Comment: The code posted looks okay. The problem is your POST reply doesn't have a property called `filtertype`. Inspect server-side handler to fix that

Comment: so you are putting the json directly in a html file ? instead save in a json file and your filter type attribute doesn't seem to of any use

Comment: Do you have any idea that how can I filter it from json to html file?

Comment: instead of `portfolio-images.html` create a file named `portfolio-images.json`. Then use $.getJson and the data parse the data based on `filtertype` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

**portfolio-images.json**

```
[
    {
        "pimg_id":"860",
        "pimg_name":"logo-1.jpg",
        "pimg_catid":"66",
        "pcat_slug":"mobile-apps",
        "pcat_name":"Mobile Apps"
    },
    {
        "pimg_id":"702",
        "pimg_name":"logo-2.jpg",
        "pimg_catid":"52",
        "pcat_slug":"illustrations",
        "pcat_name":"Illustrations"
    },
    {
        "pimg_id":"153",
        "pimg_name":"logo-3.jpg",
        "pimg_catid":"15",
        "pcat_slug":"animals",
        "pcat_name":"Animals"
    },
    {
        "pimg_id":"926",
        "pimg_name":"logo-4.jpg",
        "pimg_catid":"71",
        "pcat_slug":"real-estate",
        "pcat_name":"Real Estate"
    },
    {
        "pimg_id":"515",
        "pimg_name":"logo-5.jpg",
        "pimg_catid":"41",
        "pcat_slug":"event-managment",
        "pcat_name":"Event Managment"
    },
    {
        "pimg_id":"1060",
        "pimg_name":"logo-6.jpg",
        "pimg_catid":"78",
        "pcat_slug":"technology",
        "pcat_name":"Technology"
    },
    {
        "pimg_id":"1043",
        "pimg_name":"logo-7.jpg",
        "pimg_catid":"78",
        "pcat_slug":"technology",
        "pcat_name":"Technology"
    },
    {
        "pimg_id":"987",
        "pimg_name":"logo-8.jpg",
        "pimg_catid":"74",
        "pcat_slug":"restaurants",
        "pcat_name":"Restaurants"
    },
    {
        "pimg_id":"1053",
        "pimg_name":"logo-9.jpg",
        "pimg_catid":"78",
        "pcat_slug":"technology",
        "pcat_name":"Technology"
    }
]
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".portfolio-style").hide();
    $(".homeportfolioloader").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data) {
            var li = "";
            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                li += "<li class='" + value.pcat_slug + "'><img src='images/portfolio/logo/" + value.pcat_slug + "/" + value.pimg_name + "'/></li>";
            });
            $(".portfolio-style").empty();
            $(".portfolio-style").append(li);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".homeportfolioloader").hide();
                $('.portfolio-style').fadeIn(800);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

    $(".current").click(function() {
        $(".portfolio-style").hide();
        $(".homeportfolioloader").show();
        $('.portfolioFilter  a.current22').removeClass('current');
        $('.portfolioFilter  a.current22').removeClass('current22');
        $('.portfolioFilter  a i.pf-icon1-active').removeClass('pf-icon1-active');

        $(this).addClass('current22');
        $(this).children("i").addClass('pf-icon1-active');
        var filtertype = $(this).data("filter");
        console.log(filtertype);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'data.json',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var li = "";
                    console.log("Filter Type: " + filtertype);
                    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                        if (filtertype === "all") {
                            li += "<li class='" + value.pcat_slug + "'><img src='images/portfolio/logo/" + value.pcat_slug + "/" + value.pimg_name + "'/></li>";
                        }
                        console.log(filtertype);
                        if (value.pcat_slug === filtertype) {
                            li += "<li class='" + value.pcat_slug + "'><img src='images/portfolio/logo/" + value.pcat_slug + "/" + value.pimg_name + "'/></li>";
                        }
                    });
                    $(".portfolio-style").empty();
                    $(".portfolio-style").append(li);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".homeportfolioloader").hide();
                        $('.portfolio-style').fadeIn(800);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Html**

```
<h1>Get Data Using Json</h1>
<div class="portfolio-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="current" data-filter="all" style="cursor: pointer !important;">All</a></li>
        <li><a class="current" data-filter="mobile-apps" style="cursor: pointer !important;">Mobile Apps</a></li>
        <li><a class="current" data-filter="illustrations" style="cursor: pointer !important;">Illustrations</a></li>
        <li><a class="current" data-filter="animals" style="cursor: pointer !important;">Animals</a></li>
        <li><a class="current" data-filter="real-estate" style="cursor: pointer !important;">Real Estate</a></li>
        <li><a class="current" data-filter="event-managment" style="cursor: pointer !important;">Event Management</a></li>
        <li><a class="current" data-filter="restaurants" style="cursor: pointer !important;">Restaurants</a></li>
        <li><a class="current" data-filter="technology" style="cursor: pointer !important;">Technology</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="homeportfolioloader" style="display: none;"></div>
<ul class="portfolio-style"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. It is working perfect. But if you don't mind. I want to ask a question. Please see this link: "https://www.brandedlogodesigns.com/portfolio-images.html". Whenever I refresh the page after open this link. it is showing new items on every refresh. How is it happening?

Comment: When I put 50 items in data.json file. That is showing all items on load. But I have to load only 10 items on page load. How may I do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then you have to write a webservice which returns json based on your requirement. and to your portfolio-image.html I dont think its acutal html file. is it hosted by you

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your reply. Do you have any idea about that or any reference guide with the help of that I can write webservice?

Comment: do you have idea on php ?

Comment: No I did not hosted that.

Comment: Yes. I know about php. You mean I will have to pass data using json_encode?

Comment: or else you splice the response object by using `var newArray = data.splice(0,10);` and do foreach on that

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code.

```
$( ".current" ).click(function() {
$(".portfolio-style").hide();
$(".homeportfolioloader").show();

        var filtertype = $(this).data("filter");
        $.ajax({
        url:'portfolio-images.html',
        type:'POST',
        dataType:"json",
        data:JSON.stringify({filtertype: filtertype}),
        success:function(data){
         console.log(data);
        if(data){
            var li  = "";
            console.log(filtertype);
            $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
                li +="<li class='"+value.pcat_slug+"'><img src='images/portfolio/logo/"+value.pcat_slug+"/"+value.pimg_name+"'/></li>";
            });
            $(".portfolio-style").empty();
            $(".portfolio-style").append(li);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(".homeportfolioloader").hide();
                $('.portfolio-style').fadeIn(800);
            }, 4000); 
        }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello, Still showing "undefine" erro. My code is this: url:'portfolio-images.html',
   type:'POST',
   dataType:"json",
   data:JSON.stringify({filtertype: filtertype}),

Comment: @Learner Check updated code . console your variable filtertype.

Comment: When you will click on left category which I have give you link. That is showing this: "http://globaloid.com/json-work/images/portfolio/logo/undefined/undefined 404 (Not Found)" error in console.

Comment: <img src='images/portfolio/logo/"+value.pcat_slug+"/"+value.pimg_name+"'/></li>" check this . value.pcat_slug and value.pimg_name . these two values are undefined because data.filtertype is undefined .

Comment: This is a data-filter value: var filtertype = $(this).data("filter");
I have to use above value here: $.each(data.filtertype, function( index, value )
I have 5 categories. That's why I have to define it dynamically. I cannot define it as a string. Any Idea?

Comment: alright put your all code inside success . done does not wait for the ajax success response @Learner . Check updated answer

Comment: I have done that but now showing error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined". On if condition:   if(data){
   var li  = "";
   console.log(filtertype);
   $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
    li +="<li class='"+value.pcat_slug+"'><img src='images/portfolio/logo/"+value.pcat_slug+"/"+value.pimg_name+"'/></li>";
   });
   $(".portfolio-style").empty();
   $(".portfolio-style").append(li);
   setTimeout(function(){
    $(".homeportfolioloader").hide();
    $('.portfolio-style').fadeIn(800);
   }, 4000); 
  }

Comment: success:function(data){

    //put all your code after success here . (code on done part) . as done does not wait for the ajax success response . only success will give it for you . 
         }  . see code again . check if data is referenced or not

Comment: I have already put my all code in success function. Please see my update code above...

Comment: can you console data after success . as updated in answer

Comment: That is showing same error:  "http://globaloid.com/json-work/images/portfolio/logo/undefined/undefined 404 (Not Found)"
You may check it again live: http://globaloid.com/json-work/

Comment: please console data after success. console.log(data) if(data){----}

Comment: Actually I want same functionality like this website: https://www.brandedlogodesigns.com/. Please scroll down in "A Glimpse Of Our Work" section. Any idea about this?

Comment: I have done that and show this in console: Object {mobileapps: Array[2], illustrations: Array[2]}

Comment: You may see screen shot for idea how is showing data in console: http://globaloid.com/json-work/Untitled-1.png

Comment: you are making some common mistake , please create a fiddle so we can edit it there . as right now whole code is in your index file and it can't be edited from console .

Comment: When I define object array as a string it works fine but just for one. Please see this code: "$.each(data.mobileapps, function( index, value )". There is **mobileapps** is a string. But I have to define it dynamically according to left category.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93503/discussion-between-learner-and-creator).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the response content type i think you are calling the HTML page and so it will be something else it content type must be `application/json`